# How to load multiple jmeter property files in CLI mode

Tags: jmeter

It was possible to load an additional JMeter property file with the command line argument -q
But not sure how to load **multiple** JMeter property files to JMeter.

```
-q, --addprop <argument>
additional JMeter property file(s)
```

How to incorporate multiple jmeter property files using -q argument?

I tried by separating the files with commas and spaces.

Comment: Did you tried multiple -q: `-q a -q b` ...

Comment: Thanks @user7294900. It worked with multiple -q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked

```
./jmeter.sh  -q jm-new.properties -q jm-new2.properties
```